# Word for making a statement, consciously left open to interpretation while maintaining plausible deniability for any interpretation

Tags: word-request

As the title says: I'm looking for a single verb to describe the act of making a statement that is consciously left open to interpretation, with the purpose of instilling a certain interpretation within some people, while at the same time maintaining plausible deniability for that interpretation to others.

It's something politicians and other public figures tend to be good at. The direct motivation for me asking is that the act was recently covered in the satirical late-night show Last Week Tonight in a segment on Ivanka Drumpf. However, no term for it was mentioned.

Comment: How would you like to use this verb? An adjective to describe this would be [ambiguous](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ambiguous), or it can be used as the adverb **ambiguously**.

Comment: How about [**equivocate**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/equivocate)?

Comment: @StoneyB: now there is a word I didn't know! It comes amazingly close to what I had in mind. If you'd be so kind to post it as an answer, I'll accept it as one.

Comment: @SteveES: I'd like it to be used as simple as possible; like "You're walking" I'd like to be able to say: "You're...".  My main reason for asking was that I had hopes for a single word acknowledging the existence of this phenomenon. While "You're equivocating!" isn't as easily said as I had liked, it seems to mean pretty much what I had in mind.

Comment: @Mr.H While "equivocate" is a) a great word, and b) might well be the answer to your question, I would issue a word of warning if you are thinking of using it while speaking to someone - it's not in common parlance, so you might have to explain the meaning to/not be understood by some people. [See the Ngram, comparing to ambiguous](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=equivocate%2Cambiguous&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cequivocate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cambiguous%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @StoneyB I would also say that "equivocate" implies (to me) a deliberate vagueness (i.e. lack of details, confusing language, or language that sounds like it says a lot, while actually saying nothing), rather than necessarily implying multiple interpretations (which ambiguous does).

Comment: @SteveES Ambiguity lies at the root sense of *equivocate*: etymologically it's "same-voice". M-W defines *equivocate* as "to use *equivocal* language especially with intent to deceive", and gives the primary sense of *equivocal* as "subject to two or more interpretations and usually used to mislead or confuse".

Answer (score -1):

When we [imply](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=imply&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Xyz_WJDpJMX48AeK8ZnICQ) something, we are doing exactly what you said: making a statement that is consciously left open to interpretation.

As for the part about "maintaining plausible deniability," you just have to remember:

We imply while others [infer](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=infer&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=2iz_WPGSN8X48AeK8ZnICQ).

What I mean is that because we leave things "open to interpretation," it's possible for things to be interpreted in a way that we had not intended (as many politicians, celebrities and other people of interest may often attest to).

Or perhaps, it is possible for things to be interpreted as intended, but vehemently denied (as in your example).

Or perhaps, not denied, as in the example below:

[image: We implied; you inferred.]

> Imply: indicate the truth or existence of (something) by suggestion rather than explicit reference
>
> - "salesmen who use jargon to *imply* superior knowledge"
>
> Infer: deduce or conclude (something) from evidence and reasoning rather than from explicit statements
>
> - "from these facts we can *infer* that crime has been increasing"
>
> Google

And a funny alternative:

[image: What are you insinuating?!?!]

Comment: @ColleenV, thanks for editing my image sizes! How did you do it?

Comment: There are some tips on meta in the Formatting Sandbox post https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3318/ If you append an 'm' to the Imgur filename before the '.jpg' or other extension, it displays the medium thumbnail. The full size image is still available just by removing the 'm' so you can make clicking on the thumbnail display the full image. It's a pretty nice feature!

Comment: Thanks for your fun explanations! I was looking for a subtle kind of implying/inferring, a kind with the goal of not only suggesting something without actually saying it, but to steer (a group of) people into putting words into your mouth (be it specific words, or words in a general direction) that you don't want to be held accountable for, while their believe of you saying it plays out pretty well for you in the mean time.

Comment: We can imply something and then deny it, but deniability is not a necessary purpose for implying something.

Comment: True dat, @Tᴚoɯɐuo!

Comment: @Mr.H, both "imply" and "insinuate" will do exactly what you mean. You can Google more examples of them online (I suggest Googling "imply memes" or "infer memes" or "insinuate memes" to get images of these words in context).

Comment: Hi, @TeacherKSHuang. Really do appreciate the answer, but imply nor insinuate are exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Alas, @Mr.H, sorry about that :/. Perhaps I had misunderstood what you had been looking for. What'd you end up going with?

Comment: No problem. Really enjoyed your answer. :) I ended up going for equivocating and equivocal, fully aware that these will probably not be understood by the layman.

Comment: That indeed is almost the word you're looking for, word-for-word, @Mr.H!